# Log wcf data service (OData) request urls on the client side

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-data-services, odata

A normal OData query is just a URL.

I have a WPF App that uses WCF Data Services (OData) and I would like to be able to enable logging of every url that is sent to the server for resolution.  (To track performance issues and duplicate querying.)

Is there a way to plug into the client side calls of WCF Data Services to get this URL before it sends it off to the server?  (And ideally when it comes back to (for performance profiling of individual queries.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could listen to one of the events on `DataServiceContext` and log the request URL every time the event is fired. For example:

```
var context = new DataServiceContext(new Uri("http://services.odata.org/v3/OData/OData.svc"));
context.BuildingRequest += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.Out.WriteLine(eventArgs.RequestUri);
```

Alternatively, listening on SendingRequest2 would work as well:

```
context.SendingRequest2 += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.Out.WriteLine(eventArgs.RequestMessage.Url);
```

For logging the URL, listening on either event should be fine. If at some point, you also want to modify the outgoing URL before the request is sent, use `BuildingRequest`.

Comment: SendingRequest did it.  Thanks!